# Whitney extension theorem for Hölder spaces

Tags: reference-request, taylor-expansion, differential-topology, holder-spaces, smooth-functions

The usual [Whitney extension theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem) says that Whitney data with remainders like $R_\alpha=o(x-y)^{k-|\alpha|}$ extends to a $C^k$ function. If we also have $R_\alpha=o(x-y)^{k+\lambda-|\alpha|}$ for some $\lambda\in(0,1]$, do we get a $C^{k+\lambda}$ function? That is, a function whose $k$th derivative is $\lambda$-Hölder continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see Stein's *Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions* Chapter VI Theorem 4: https://archive.org/details/singularintegral0000stei